# Unsupported mime type error while gif resize

Tags: jimp

I am using JIMP image library with Node js for image processing. While trying to resize error I am getting Unsupported Mime type error. In the library repo it is mentioned that gif is supported.

I am using JIMP package version 0.6.4

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the project:

```
Ctrl+C
Y
npm run build
// or
// npm run dev
```